# Test .js typeof against a Flash object with ExternalInterface methods?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I've got a Flash object and I want to test if a method has been defined with `ExternalInterface`.

Can I test with `typeof` in .js?

```
if(typeof(object.testMethod) == "function"){}
```

Comment: Yep that seems to work for me in Chrome. I'm using SWFObject to embed the SWF and using the callback function to get the Flash object. If I call typeof( flash.someFunc ) in my browser's console and 'someFunc' isn't a call back in ExternalInterface, it returns undefined, however if the function is bound, it returns 'function'.